# Mount as root for non-root user

Tags: mount, privileges

How do I mount a nfs or any other share which requires usage of `-o` in the `mount` command so that the mount can be accessed by non-root user. If `mount` is user with `-o` option, it complains that only root can do that but if I do that as a root, the normal user cannot write to that because the directory becomes root to where it is mounted becomes root owned. Is there an option for mount to avoid this?

Comment: if it's in the `/etc/fstab` file, you can add the `,user` option (which allows users to mount)

Comment: I want to do it as necessary, not put it in fstab.

Comment: Is this on Linux or some other Unix?

Answer (score 1):

If you'd connect through cifs, you may want to use I.E. `dir_mode` and `file_mode` [options](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs).

This works perfectly to me, every folder and file is writable by anyone.

```
mount -t cifs //server/path -o user=username_on_server,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0776 target_dir
```

However, I don't see such an [option for nfs](https://linux.die.net/man/5/nfs).

More about NFS permissions can be found on [centos.org](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-nfs-security.html)

Comment: Isn't there an option for mount to specify user id who can write to that mount? I vaguely remember something like uuid...

Comment: UUID serves rather for filesystems :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fuse` to mount various file systems as ordinary users.

I would definitely use fuse for sshfs, encrypted fileshare, and mountable by ordinary users, provided they are allowed to ssh into the file server.